# Autofac WithKey Attribute not working as expected (multiple implementations)

Tags: autofac, linqpad

I tried to reconstruct the problem in LinqPad:

```
/*
    “Named and Keyed Services”
    http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html
*/

const string A = "a";
const string B = "b";
const string MyApp = "MyApp";

void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder
        .RegisterType<MyClassA>()
        .As<IMyInterface>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
        .Keyed<IMyInterface>(A);
    builder
        .RegisterType<MyClassB>()
        .As<IMyInterface>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
        .Keyed<IMyInterface>(B);
    builder
        .RegisterType<MyAppDomain>()
        .Named<MyAppDomain>(MyApp);

    var container = builder.Build();

    var instance = container.ResolveKeyed<IMyInterface>(A);
    instance.AddTheNumbers().Dump();

    var myApp = container.ResolveNamed<MyAppDomain>(MyApp);
    myApp.Dump();
}

interface IMyInterface
{
    int AddTheNumbers();
}

class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{
    public int AddTheNumbers() { return 1 + 2; }
}

class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    public int AddTheNumbers() { return 3 + 4; }
}

class MyAppDomain
{
    public MyAppDomain([WithKey(A)]IMyInterface aInstance, [WithKey(B)]IMyInterface bInstance)
    {
        this.ANumber = aInstance.AddTheNumbers();
        this.BNumber = bInstance.AddTheNumbers();
    }

    public int ANumber { get; private set; }

    public int BNumber { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("ANumber: {0}", this.ANumber);
        sb.AppendFormat(", BNumber: {0}", this.BNumber);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

when `MyApp` is “dumped” I am seeing `ANumber: 7, BNumber: 7` which tells me that `WithKey(A)` is not returning the expected instance. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forgot [to register the consumers using WithAttributeFilter](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) which is what allows this to work. Like:

`builder.RegisterType<ArtDisplay>().As<IDisplay>().WithAttributeFilter();`

Comment: why does Autofac require the WithAttributeFilter to be added to the consumer registration. Couldn't autofac reflect the attribute and resolve the desired service?

Comment: Reflection is expensive comparatively speaking and it's a less common use case so rather than impact the majority it's opt-in. The extension basically is that opt in to reflection.